# drupal_queues for drupal 6

Tags: 6, cron, queue

So this all starts when I hit my php memory limit, I know I can increase my php memory limit... but in order to get the process that I needed running I had to up my limit to 1026M... and I dont think that this is the right way to go.

My process needs to run using cron, so I first looked to batch processing... its very usefull and works well, except when implemented with cron.

I know see that the right path is to use the d7 backport of drupal_queues.

I would put up some code, but what I am really trying to understand is the logic behind setting up and processing a queue using drupal_queues and cron.

So far this is what I got:

I set up hook_queue_info:

```
function mymodule_cron_queue_info() {
  $queue['mymodule_queue'] = array(
      'worker callback' => '_mymodule_queue_worker',
      );
  return $queue;
}
```

I setup hook_queue_worker($item)

```
function _mymodule_queue_worker($item) {
  $acc_id = $item['acc_id'];
  //Collect list of relevant campaign ID's
  $campaignNIDs = mymodule_get_campaignNIDs($acc_id);
  dpm($campaignNIDs);
  foreach($campaignNIDs as $key => $value) {  
       $CampaignNID = $value;
       mymodule_collect_contact_actions($acc_id, $CampaignNID);
  }
}
```

And then I worked in the hook_cron

```
function mymodule_cron(){
  //Adding drupal_queue into the cron
  $items = mymodule_get_all_accounts();
  //This is the list of items that we need to itterate through
  //This will be the different ESP accounts
  $queue = drupal_queue_get('mymodule_queue'); //grab the queue
  $queue->createQueue(); //initiate the queue
  foreach ($items as $item) {
    $queue->createItem($item); //each item passed as param to worker
  }

  drupal_queue_cron_run();
```

So far this works and allows me to call each account separately in the queue. but now I have processes(functions) that need to be run per account. Ho would I add these processes as a "Sub-queue" to the queue that is currently being processed.

Do I need to do this or is what I have so far satisfactory?

Any light on this subject would be really appreciated as the documentation on this subject is somewhat lacking

Answer (score 1):

There's no concept of a "sub-queue", it's just queues, items in the queue, and workers of a queue (on items). Without knowing more about your use case I'd say you should may want to have a queue per account. Or create a queue item containing the account its for and working that way. So, you can either have many queues with some items in each or one queue with a whole bunch of items.

Comment: I have spent some time now on understanding how the queue system works and how I can use it in conjunction with batches. Queues is a very useful tool when used with batches. Thank you for your explanation :)